# Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-y)$ ill-defined?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x)=x-y$. Then
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{x+h-y_h-x+y}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h+y-y_h}{h},$$
noting that $y$ can depend on $x$ (that's why I wrote $y_h$).

Now if instead we let $f(x,y)=x-y$,
then
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x+h-y-x+y}{h}=1$$
which is, in general, not equivalent the first result.

Does this mean that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-y)$ is an ill-defined expression?

Comment: Let's define $y$, please, what you're talking about is unclear until you do so. I really dislike this "$y$ is a variable or a constant" thing. Declare a function $y:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ if you wish. As a univariate function, $\partial_x f$ is bad notation, it should just be $f'$

Comment: When you write $f(x) = x-y$ the $y$ is presumed constant and so $f'(x) = 1$.

Comment: If you note *a priori* that $y=y(x)$, then $f(x)=1-y(x)$ and $f’(x)=x-y’(x)$. Moreover, the partial derivative notation is not appropriate when you have a function of a single variable.

Comment: @FShrike $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$. We have no *a priori* information about $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$.

Comment: That hasn’t told me anything. I still don’t know if you have *fixed* a $y\in\Bbb R$ (as would be assumed without further context) or if you mean to say, there is a mapping $y$ and the mapping $f$ is defined through $x\mapsto x-y(x)$. As Shifrin says, in either case the partial notation is not appropriate. You just haven’t clearly defined what $f$ is: once you do, the question is resolved

Comment: No, but "$f(x)=x-y$" __is__ ill-defined.

Comment: One of the facts about partial derivatives I didn't really understand until I took a course in Hamiltonian Mechanics (about two years after I first took a course in multivariable calculus and a year after I took an undergrad course in PDEs) is that while _total derivatives_ make sense in the context of either expressions or functions, _partial derivatives_ only make sense in the context of functions, and the function $(x,y) \mapsto x-y$ is **not** the same as the function $x \mapsto x-y(x)$, and it's _definitely_ not the same as $y\mapsto (x \mapsto x-y)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way in which $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-y)$ is ill-defined, is the same way in which the function $x-y$ is ill-defined.  That is, the very instant we define the function $x-y$, its partials are also well-defined.

For instance:

- We define $f(x,y) = x-y$.  Then immediately we'd have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 1.$  Note that this doesn't depend on whether $x,y$ are dependent in your application, as the function $f$ itself necessarily has no information about this dependency in order to define its partials.
- We define $g(x) = x - y(x)$. Then we'd have $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 1 - y'(x)$.
- We define $G(x, t) = x-y(x,t)$.  Then we'd have $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = 1 - \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}.$ (note here that the definition of $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ requires fixing a function for $y$ in terms of $x,t$, as if we only mean $y$ depends on $x,t$, there isn't enough information to define $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$)
- In your instance of $h(x) = x-y$, this function $h$ is ill-defined, so its partials will be too.

How we define $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x-y)$ itself will be context-dependent.